# Does anyone know a way to build a Windows Installer program for a Perl script and its dependent libraries?

Tags: perl, windows-installer, oneclick

I work part-time as a computer tech at the local high school. They needed a system to keep track of all the computers in the district (things like physical location of the machines and serial numbers for inventory), and told me to keep it on a budget. I sat down and wrote a little thousand-line script in Perl/Tk, which accesses a PostgreSQL database on the local server.

I also successfully wrote a launcher in C++ and compiled it with bcc32, so they can single-click the launcher executable to start the program without having to type anything into DOS. That works fine, and I can load this program myself by manually installing all the dependencies for it by hand.

I would like to build a setup program to automatically load the PostgreSQL application, Strawberry Perl, as well as the Tk, and DBD::Pg libraries, and finally, of course, the folder my application is stored in. It'd be nice to be able to create desktop shortcuts or start menu items too.

Has anyone had any success with software to generate .MSI files for Windows Installer on Windows XP and above? If so, what did you use, and did it cost any money? Alternatively, where do I need to begin reading in order to write my own setup program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will do everything you want, but have you looked at [Win32::InstallShield](http://search.cpan.org/~kbaucom/Win32-InstallShield-0.5/lib/Win32/InstallShield.pm)?

Comment: This looks like it'll be a good learning experience over the summer. I've always wanted to learn about editing files for the InstallShield.